# I updated my Ionic-Cordova-Angular App using Angular guide from Angular 8 to Angular 14, and I am facing some runtime issues

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-appflow

I am facing this issue after upgrading. The app’s code gets compiled with a few warnings, but after opening it in the browser, it just shows a blank white screen. Nothing moves further.

Following is the configuration of the app after upgrading.

[image: versions of programs]

Error I am facing

[image: error message]

The console shows the following error.

[image: console type error]

I am new to the framework and not sure what is wrong. Here is my pacakge.json

Thank you all in advance.

I have refactored all typescript code and it does not have any syntax error.

```
{
  "name": "vsquaredapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve  --port 8000",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-preferences": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/background-fetch": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.00",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/cordova-builders": "^10.0.0",
    "async-lock": "^1.4.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.1",
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-browser": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "~6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^8.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-inputfocusfix": "^1.0.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.33.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "simple-pdf-viewer": "^2.0.3",
    "sql.js": "^1.9.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.17",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1402.13",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.13",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^14.2.13",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^14.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.3.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy": "1.5.8",
    "@ionic/lab": "2.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^7.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-inputfocusfix": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```